# How can i get google play to show localized descriptions for my app?

Tags: translation, google-play

I have developed an app and uploaded it to google play. In the developer console i set up descriptions for both english and portuguese, but for some reason google play will always show the default (english) description no matter where i access it from. Even the screenshots and video will always show as the default english version rather than the localized version. Why is this happening? I'm sure i set up both languages correctly as described on google play's step by step tutorial.